# BigQuery View Difficulty

Tags: google-bigquery, view

Hello I am trying to create a view, but I keep getting an error no matter what I do. Additionally, I'm using BigQuery.

The error is: Unexpected string literal "DeathCountPerCountry" at [1:13], or with backticks or Table "DeathCountPerCountry" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table). I'm a beginner and I'm stuck please help!

```
Create View "DeathCountPerCountry" 
AS
SELECT Location, MIN(cast(total_deaths AS integer)) AS lowestdeathcount
FROM `sql-covid-project.covid_data.covid_worldwide`
WHERE continent is not null
Group by location 
## order by lowestdeathcount desc
```

Detailed above I tried backticks and "" and neither let me make the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a dataset into which to place your view. It looks like you have a dataset called covid_data so try this

```sql
Create View covid_data.DeathCountPerCountry 
AS
SELECT Location, MIN(cast(total_deaths AS integer)) AS lowestdeathcount
FROM `sql-covid-project.covid_data.covid_worldwide`
WHERE continent is not null
Group by location
```